# Changing background images

Tags: css, background-image, footer, repeat

I am fairly new to code and taking baby steps with an issue I am having: swapping out background images. I made **very** slight adjustments to the three images that make up the background of the site. One was a main background image (in a bodywrap container) that loaded just fine. The next was a wrapper image with a repeat-y attribute that is no longer taking since the swap - the image shows up, but is just showing up as a single white line, while it is meant to 'fill' the rest of the page. Finally, the footer image is not showing up at all.

I thought that swapping out the current images with ones that were only slightly adjusted in photoshop (all I did was remove drop-shadows and red margins) would be an easy task - my mistake!

I tried adjusting the code and got nowhere, so I've copied the original code. I believe that the problem lies within my CSS:

```
#wrapper, footer, .pagetop, .copyright {
width:942px; 
margin:0 auto; 
padding:0px 37px 0px 37px; 
overflow:hidden; 
clear:both; 
}

.bodywrap {
background: url(images/background.png) 49.9% 0% repeat-x; 
width:1016px; 
margin:auto; 
overflow:hidden;
}

#wrapper { 
background: url(images/wrapper.png) 49% repeat-y; 
clear:both; 
padding-bottom:25px; 
min-height:225px;
}  

.footer {
background: url(images/footer.png) no-repeat 51% 0%; 
overflow:hidden; 
min-height:107px; 
font-size:1.2em; 
padding-top:17px;
font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
}
```

Thanks in advance for sharing your expertise!

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see that your background instructions are not consistent. Your no-repeat is before and after your alignment values. I would suggest to try keeping it the same everywhere in your code. when your code gets heavy it can be confusing.

```
body {
    background: #ffffff url("img_tree.png") no-repeat right top;
}


right means align the image on the x axe to the right and
top means align the image on the y axe to the top
```

Do you understand that your 49.9% values are telling the background image to start repeating at 49% to the left from the edge of the box you as it to be in.

Also your `.bodywrap` does not have a height. if you only see a small line, this is because your element is only taking up the space the content inside this element is taking. you might have a space or 1 line of code. hard to say without the HTML.

So you need to give the `.bodywrap` element a min-height or height equal to your image height. The image you provide AS background to an element, does not define that element's height. The `<img>` tag and an image background don't work the same. an `<img>` tag will determine its height on its own but you cannot repeat it like a background.

Here you can see more information on background here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp